# counterfactual if-clause and gerund

Tags: conditionals, gerunds

It appears that counterfactual if-clauses can modify gerunds, as the following demonstrates:

> A: What would you do if you were a billionaire?

> B: I would buy a caslte. Buying a medieval building **if I were megarich** sounds so great.

Does the if-clause modify the gerund phrase alone or the whole sentence? Do you have any arguments for your stand?

Comment: "Buying a medieval building if I were megarich" is the VP of a gerund-participial clause functioning as subject. It consists of three immediate constituents: "buying (predicator) +  "a building" (Od) + "if I were megarich" (conditional adjunct), the latter functioning as modifier of the VP. It's the idea of buying a medieval building if you were megarich that sounds so great.

Comment: Is it correct to move the if-clause to the beginning of the sentence and say "If I were megarich, buying a medieval building sounds so great" in the dialogue?

Comment: No, you need "would", as in "If I were megarich, buying a medieval building would sound so great".

Comment: @BillJ If "Buying a medieval building if I were megarich sounds so great" had not been presented in that dialogue, would you have found it ungrammatical?